Generate and write to file a random matrix in a distributed, balanced way with MPI
I am trying to generate a random 4x4 matrix in a parallel, "even" way: given the 1D array (representing a matrix) dimension N (e.g. 16 in this case) and the number of processes NP, each process generates N/NP values for the matrix (not necessarily aligned with the row dimensions, to achieve load balancing between all the processes - just as an 1D vector, I will treat that as a matrix in a proper way in some further steps, it is not required here), then each process writes the generated part of matrix to a file. I am currently trying to run the following code with 8 processes (see below for the run command):
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int size, rank;

int distribute_elems_count(int elems_no) {
    int base_elems = elems_no / size;
    int spare_elems = elems_no % size;
    return rank < spare_elems ? ++base_elems : base_elems;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm comm;
    MPI_Comm_dup(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm);


    MPI_Comm_size(comm, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &rank);

    int max = 30, min = -30;
    int rows = 4, cols = 4;

    // generating by columns
    int elements_count = distribute_elems_count(rows * cols);

    double *part = (double *) malloc(elements_count * sizeof(double));

    // random value generation
    for (int i = 0; i < elements_count; i++) {
        part[i] = rand() % (max + 1 - min) + min;
        printf("[proc. %d] generated: %f\n", rank, part[i]);
    }


    int rank_norm = rank / cols;
    char *filename = "filename";


    MPI_Datatype filetype;
    MPI_File file;

    MPI_Status status;
    int gsizes[1], distribs[1], dargs[1], psizes[1];

    gsizes[0] = rows * cols; // size of the main matrix (1d array)
    distribs[0] = MPI_DISTRIBUTE_BLOCK; // block distribution
    dargs[0] = elements_count;
    psizes[0] = size; // all processes can work

    MPI_Type_create_darray(size, rank_norm, 1,
                           gsizes, distribs, dargs, psizes,
                           MPI_ORDER_C, MPI_DOUBLE, &filetype);


    MPI_Type_commit(&filetype);

    MPI_File_open(comm, filename,
                  MPI_MODE_CREATE | MPI_MODE_RDWR, MPI_INFO_NULL, &file);


    MPI_File_set_view(file, 0, MPI_DOUBLE, filetype, "native", MPI_INFO_NULL);


    MPI_File_write_all(file, part,size, MPI_DOUBLE, &status);


    MPI_Barrier(comm);
    MPI_File_close(&file);
    printf("proc. %d still alive at the end\n", rank);


    return 0;
}

The way I compile and run it is the following:
$ rm -f filename && mpicc -Wall test2.c && mpirun -np 8 --oversubscribe ./a.out
[proc. 0] generated: -1.000000
[proc. 0] generated: 24.000000
[proc. 2] generated: -1.000000
[proc. 2] generated: 24.000000
[proc. 4] generated: -1.000000
[proc. 4] generated: 24.000000
[proc. 1] generated: -1.000000
[proc. 3] generated: -1.000000
[proc. 3] generated: 24.000000
[proc. 5] generated: -1.000000
[proc. 5] generated: 24.000000
[proc. 1] generated: 24.000000
[proc. 6] generated: -1.000000
[proc. 6] generated: 24.000000
[proc. 7] generated: -1.000000
[proc. 7] generated: 24.000000
proc. 3 still alive at the end
proc. 7 still alive at the end
proc. 0 still alive at the end
proc. 2 still alive at the end
proc. 6 still alive at the end
proc. 4 still alive at the end
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun has exited due to process rank 6 with PID 0 on
node compaq exiting improperly. There are three reasons this could occur:

1. this process did not call "init" before exiting, but others in
the job did. This can cause a job to hang indefinitely while it waits
for all processes to call "init". By rule, if one process calls "init",
then ALL processes must call "init" prior to termination.

2. this process called "init", but exited without calling "finalize".
By rule, all processes that call "init" MUST call "finalize" prior to
exiting or it will be considered an "abnormal termination"

3. this process called "MPI_Abort" or "orte_abort" and the mca parameter
orte_create_session_dirs is set to false. In this case, the run-time cannot
detect that the abort call was an abnormal termination. Hence, the only
error message you will receive is this one.

This may have caused other processes in the application to be
terminated by signals sent by mpirun (as reported here).

You can avoid this message by specifying -quiet on the mpirun command line.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

I expect the final matrix to be something like this:
-1 24 -1 24
-1 24 -1 24
-1 24 -1 24
-1 24 -1 24

with each process generating 2 items each for the matrix, like this:
proc. 0 -> -1 24
proc. 1 -> -1 24 // end of 1st row
proc. 2 -> -1 24
proc. 3 -> -1 24 // end of 2nd row
proc. 4 -> -1 24
proc. 5 -> -1 24 // end of 3rd row
proc. 6 -> -1 24
proc. 7 -> -1 24 // end of 4th row

(rand() has poor randomization and seed is uninitialized, but this is not a problem right now - it is actually useful for debugging)
When I try to read back the file, I have some garbage like this:
$ od -t f8 filename 
0000000                       -1                       24
*
0000040          2,12202817e-314                        0
0000060                3,16e-322                        0
0000100                        0                        0
*
0000200                 1,6e-322                6,37e-322
0000220                 1,6e-322                   4e-322
0000240                        0                        0
*
0000400   2,437226570133198e-152   4,824071254712238e+228
0000420     6,9023403697521e-310                   5e-324
0000440                        0                        0
*
0000600   2,645218138042807e+185   3,946618425203878e+180
0000620    8,66284807723416e+217   1,384331367053311e+219
0000640

What am I missing? I think something is wrong with the parameters I pass to MPI_Type_Create_darray. I also would let this code work with an arbitrary number of processes (e.g. with different elements_count for each process), but right now I would just be happy to make it work with equal numbers of matrix value generated.

For a 4x4 matrix, the overhead of parallelism far outweighs any benefit from running the code in multiple processes.  For a 400x400 matrix, you might get some benefit, but I'd want to measure to be sure about that.  I don't see code that ensures that each of the sub-processes writes to a different section of the file, or that sequences the outputs so that one sub-process doesn't interfere with another.  However, I'm not familiar with MPI and specifically not with MPI_File_write_all() (which might be doing that job).

you should write element_counts elements (and not size). I am not sure about rank_norm.

When writing a [mcve], please do not use random numbers. Instead, use simple values that make it trivial to test the result is correct.

Thank you for your comments. I am aware that, for a 4x4 matrix, letting the processes build the matrix in a parallel way is absolutely suboptimal: this program aims to do it with much larger matrices, the 4x4 example is for debugging purpose only.
Also, the "random" numbers are here the same for all the runs, given the "raw" usage of the rand() function, so in this case I think this choice could be good for debugging in the same way. Anyways, I will remember that for my future questions.

By the way, I am trying to substitute size with element_counts in the write function, as well as using rank instead of rank_norm, but I still can't figure out what is wrong...

so update your question and describe the discrepancy between the actual vs expected result.

Update: I managed to solve the problem in a different way, that is by calculating the offsets in parallel for every process, and then reducing them via MPI_Exscan. Thank you for your help!
